# how to insert heikinashi filter in this script?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, indicator

Guys how to insert heikinashi filter in this script? I want this indicator to calculate based on these candles on a chart with ordinary Japanese candles.

```
//@version=4
study("Trend Step", overlay=true)
length = input(50)
src = close
//
dev = stdev(src, length) * 2
//
a = 0.
a := bar_index < length ? src : 
   src > nz(a[1], src) + dev ? src : src < nz(a[1], src) - dev ? src : a[1]
//
plot(a, color=color.lime, linewidth=2, transp=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

See how HA calcs are done in [Heiken-Ashi Candles](https://www.tradingview.com/script/qRNix8Bh-Heiken-Ashi-Candles/) by allanster.

Comment: In this article, the author simply imposed a separate indicator on the chart! but I wrote about how to put a filter function in code. Feel the difference ??? maybe I'm writing badly ..?

Comment: Once you have the HA values calculated as they are in that script, you can use their OHLC values to calculate any filter you want, even if the chart is running on normal candles.

Comment: Excuse me, please comment on whether I understood you correctly? should I extract this heikenashi code to insert into my indicator later? that is, so I can create a variable in my indicator based on this heikenashi code and build a filter?